# How to get this Simple WCF REST client working?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest

I try to call this URI from inside my application: http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCEUR/ticker?raw

Using this code as ServiceContract:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "/api/1")]
public interface ITickerService
{
    //base uri: "http://data.mtgox.com";

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "{ident}{currency}/ticker?raw")]
    String GetTicker(String ident, String currency);
}
```

And this calling code

```
BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

EndpointAddress mtGoxEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://data.mtgox.com/");
ChannelFactory<ITickerService> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ITickerService>(myBinding, mtGoxEndpoint);

ITickerService tickerService = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

// Stops here till timeout after 1 min
var result = tickerService.GetTicker("BTC", "EUR");
```

Any Idea what can be wrong?

Tanks, Tarion

Comment: Just suggest, if you have right to opt, leave REST WCF, come to Web Api, simpler

Comment: You have any references? I'm just starting with implementing the client and I'm free to choose. - But I have a WinForms app.

Comment: The link to start: http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: Does it work in WinForms?

Comment: Seems you are consuming data from you Win App to rest service?

Comment: Yes, I have a winForms app that should simply consume the rest service. Can't be that hard to do this with WCF.

Comment: Try the new toy: HttpClient from MS http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Introduction-to-HttpClient-4a2d9cee, easier